XSLT using group-adjacent when I want to make two groups with different criteria
I have an HTML file that I want to convert to a form.
<p class="textfield">Text field</p>
<p class="checkboxfield">Check Box field</p>
<p class="drop_downlistfield">Drop-down list field 1</p>
<p class="drop_downlistfield">Drop-down list field 2</p>
<p class="drop_downlistfield">Drop-down list field 3</p>
<p class="radiobuttonfield">Radio Button field 1</p>
<p class="radiobuttonfield">Radio Button field 2</p>
<p class="radiobuttonfield">Radio Button field 3</p>
<p class="submitbuttonfield">Submit button</p>

To do this, I have to create groups: the paragraphs with class="drop_downlistfield" have to become one group:
<select>
  <option value="Drop-down list field 1">Drop-down list field 1</option>
  <option value="Drop-down list field 2">Drop-down list field 2</option>
  <option value="Drop-down list field 3">Drop-down list field 3</option>
</select>

and the paragraphs with class="radiobuttonfield" have to become another group, grouped by their @name attribute.
<input type="radio" id="ID_1929_6" name="radiogroup"></input>
<label for="ID_1929_6">Radio Button field 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="ID_1929_7" name="radiogroup"></input>
<label for="ID_1929_7">Radio Button field 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="ID_1929_8" name="radiogroup"></input>
<label for="ID_1929_8">Radio Button field 3</label>

I can create one group:
<xsl:for-each-group select="table|p|ul|ol" group-adjacent="(@class='radiobuttonfield')">

but I have trouble creating two. This creates one group that contains both:
<xsl:for-each-group select="table|p|ul|ol" group-adjacent="(@class='radiobuttonfield') or (@class='drop_downlistfield')">

How can I split this input fragment into two separate groups?

Where are those name attributes? I only see class attributes and using group-adjacent="@class" might work

the paragraphs with @class=radiobuttonfield have to be grouped into a series of  elements that have the same @name attribute

group-adjacent="@class does work, I was assuming I'd need to specify only the elements to be grouped in the group-adjacent attribute.

Just group them by the value of that @class-attribute. Something like this:
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <div>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="table|p|ul|ol" group-adjacent="@class">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@class='drop_downlistfield'">
            <select>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </select>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@class='radiobuttonfield'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
              <!-- some business logic is needed for naming the radiogroup -->
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>    
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

